# How do I re-calibrate my laptop battery? I can't fully drain it, it shuts down at 60%

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, battery, calibration

I'm trying to re-calibrate my battery on my Razer Blade 2015.  When on battery, it shuts down in just a few minutes at around 60-80% reported battery life.  If I plug it back in, it still shows 60-80%.  I'm trying to drain it to 0% so I can charge it back to full and thus re-calibrating it (I hope).

I've tried uninstalling the "Microsoft ACPI Compliant Control Method Battery" driver, but it didn't help.  I'm on Windows 8.1 (64 bit).

Comment: I don't think that sort of "calibration" even works on lithium batteries? AFAIK it's even outright harmful to them.

Comment: @grawity It’s not the battery that’s calibrated, but the charge level display, remaining time and whatnot. Colloquially still known as battery calibration, because these values may very well come from the batteries internal control circuit. // That being said, if it shuts down after a few minutes, it’s broken and needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, draining lithium batteries is extremely harmful and could damage it even more than it already is. I *don't* advise you to do that.

The fact that it shuts down at 60% could actually mean that it is damaged. I suggest you to try with a brand new battery and check whether you have the same problem.

If so, it could indeed be a software problem of calibration, or in the worst case a hardware problem of the battery controller.

Keep us posted !